# Convert multiple .deflate files into one gzip file in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, gzip, deflate

I ran one hadoop job which has generated multiple .deflate files. Now these files are stored on S3. So, i cannot run `hadoop fs -text /somepath` command it will take the hdfs path. Now, i want to convert multiple files stored on s3 in .deflate format into one gzip file.

Answer (score 0):

If you make gzip files instead, using the GzipCodec, you can simply concatenate them to make one large gzip file.

You can wrap a deflate stream with a gzip header and trailer, as described in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).  A fixed 10-byte header, and an 8-byte trailer that is computed from the uncompressed data.  So you will need to decompress each .deflate stream in order to compute its CRC-32 and uncompressed length to put in the trailer.

Comment: but, i already have files in .deflate format. So, how do i convert them to gzip that is my question.